# Import Image Plane Lacks Normals?

Tags: image, normals, extrude

i'm trying to import an image as a plane, to be cut up and extruded into a mesh.  However, the plane seems to have no normals (face orientation is ticked on in the settings, no blue or red shows up), which means extruding it into a cube gives weird shading results.  Adding a plane and appending the desired image to it in the shader nodes doesnt have these issues.

Any idea why this is happeneing, and how to resolve it?  Thanks in advance [image]

Answer (score 1):

By default a *Images as Planes* object has the *Show Backface* option enabled in the *Material > Settings*, disable this option and you'll be able to see the face orientations:

[image]